# Is it possible to have two gerunds consequently?

Tags: grammaticality, gerunds, grammaticality-in-context, gerund-clauses

Is it correct to say "more and more people are **quitting buying** CD's and DVD's because of the ..........."   ? 
Please help me, I'm writing an essay and this doubt is making me go crazy.

Answer (score 0):

Some verbs "take" ing with the next verb:

- to stop, finish, quit

- to start, commence, begin

Verbs that mean to start or to stop are followed by a gerund. The list I give here is not exhaustive.

Examples:
Please stop working now.
Please finish washing up now.
Quit saying that.
They quit playing CDs ten minutes ago.
We started playing last night

Please note: there are also verbs that can be followed either by ING or TO. These verbs include: like, love and hate
I like to play tennis.
I like playing tennis.